# Apache File permissions issue in Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, file-permissions

I'm trying to use Apache to access a file on my Documents folder.

I tried the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/$USER/public_html
sudo adduser $USER www-data
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/$USER/public_html
```

As suggested by this post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/26848/permissions-issue-how-can-apache-access-files-in-my-home-directory

Although this works, now I cannot edit or the files directly as the user (without using `sudo`), despite being a member of the `www-data` group. The only solution that seemed to work is using `chmod -R 777` (which I rather not do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do is restart the OS and it was sorted!